# How can I turn an int (minutes) into a Duration in java?

Tags: java, time, duration

I'm trying to compare a duration to an integer representing minutes (so another duration) in order to find out if it's a longer or shorter time. I'm trying to use compareTo(Duration duration) method but I can't use an int as parameter. How would I transform that int (minutes) into Duration?

Comment: what Duration class are you using?

Comment: java.time.Duration

Comment: Duration.ofMinutes(minutesInt)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a duration in minutes with the [`ofMinutes`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html#ofMinutes(long)) static method. So, as a silly example

```
int compareDurations(Duration d) {
    int myMinutes = 5;
    Duration durationInMinutes = Duration.ofMinutes(myMinutes);
    return d.compareTo(durationMinutes);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I always find code involving `compareTo()` hard to read. Therefore for most purposes I would prefer to do it the other way around: convert your `Duration` to minutes and compare using plain `<` or `>`.

```
    int minutes = 7;
    Duration dur = Duration.ofMinutes(7).plusSeconds(30);
    
    if (minutes > dur.toMinutes()) {
        System.out.println("The minutes are longer");
    } else {
        System.out.println("The minutes are shorter or the same");
    }
```

Output:

> The minutes are shorter or the same

If you need to know whether the minutes are strictly shorter, the code will be a bit longer, of course (no joke intended). One way does involve converting the minutes to a `Duration` in some cases:

```
    if (minutes > dur.toMinutes()) {
        System.out.println("The minutes are longer");
    } else if (Duration.ofMinutes(minutes).equals(dur)) {
        System.out.println("The minutes are the same");
    } else {
        System.out.println("The minutes are shorter");
    }
```

> The minutes are shorter

I really wish the `Duration` class had had methods `isLonger()` and `isShorter()` (even though the names just suggested may not be quite clear when it comes to negative durations). Then I would have recommended converting the minutes to a `Duration` too as in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

One way, with [Duration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html):

```java
Duration duration = Duration.of(10, ChronoUnit.SECONDS);
int seconds = 5;
System.out.println(duration.getSeconds() - seconds);
```

Note, that [ChronoUnit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html) has a lot of useful constant members, like *`MINUTES`*, *`DAYS`*, *`WEEKS`*, *`CENTURIES`*, etc.

Another way, with [LocalTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html):

```java
LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.of(0, 0, 15); //hh-mm-ss
int seconds = 5;
System.out.println(localTime.getSecond() - seconds);
```